# QStandardItemModel appendRow doesn't work after constructor was called

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I have a `TreeView` in `Qt Quick` and a class subclassing `QStandardItemModel`. `this.appendRow()` works perfectly fine in the constructor of the model.

However, if I call it after the constructor, for example as a reaction to some button press, it does nothing at all.

(Also checked `this->rowCount()` to see if it maybe just isn't displayed, but the rowCount doesn't increase).

I'm using the addRootEntry function you can see below to add an `QStandardItem` to the root.

```
void ProjectTreeModel::addRootEntry( const QString& name, const QString&  type, const QString& icon)
{
QStandardItem rootEntry = new QStandardItem( name );

rootEntry->setData( icon, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Icon );
rootEntry->setData( type, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Type );
rootEntry->setData( name, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Name );

this->appendRow(rootEntry);
qDebug() << rootEntry; //Is not null
qDebug() << this->rowCount(); //Stays the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `addRootEntry` function:

```
QStandardItem *rootEntry = new QStandardItem(name);

rootEntry->setData( icon, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Icon );
rootEntry->setData( type, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Type );
rootEntry->setData( name, ProjectTreeModel_Role_Name );

QStandardItem *parentItem = invisibleRootItem();
parentItem->appendRow(rootEntry);
```

Make sure
`ProjectTreeModel_Role_Name` is set to `Qt::DisplayRole`.

Make sure you set the `model` property on the `TreeView`.

Consider not subclassing `QStandardItemModel` as it is not typically necessary.

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work. The items are added now, but the TreeView isn't updated.